# SQL Server CE exception InvalidDatabaseFormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, windows, sql-server-ce

I am trying to call this function:

```
public Exception SetData(string Data)
{
    public string conectionstring = "Data Source=MyData1.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=as!;File Mode=Read Write; persist Security Info=False;LCID= 1033";

    query = "Insert into [CopyData] values (@data)";
    try
    {
        con = new SqlCeConnection(conectionstring);
        com = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data",Data);con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

By `Main()` using code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DB cdb = new DB();
        string b = "hello";
        Exception e = cdb.SetData(b);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this exception

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeInvalidDatabaseFormatException
>
> The
>   database file has been created by earlier version of SQL Server Compact.
>   Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()

I try to resolve it by calling `SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()` as

```
public Exception SetData(string Data)
{
    public string conectionstring = "Data Source=MyData1.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=as!;File Mode=Read Write; persist Security Info=False;LCID= 1033";
    public string conectionstringc = "Data Source=MyData1.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=as!;File Mode=Read Write; persist Security Info=False;LCID= 1033;Case Sensitive=true";
    query = "Insert into [CopyData] values (@data)";
    try
    {
        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(conectionstring);
        engine.Upgrade(conectionstringc);
        con = new SqlCeConnection(conectionstring);
        com = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data",Data);con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

But then this exception came up

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
>
> Database upgrade is not required, the database is already in a compatible format

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of the Systsem.data.SqlServerCe.dll does your project reference and which database file vesion is Mydatabase.sdf ?

Comment: Systsem.data.SqlServerCe.dll  version 4.0.8876.1  . I don't know how  to get the version of database file .

Comment: Perhaps [this blog post](http://erikej.blogspot.nl/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html) might help you. At least it contains a function to determine the version of the `sdf` file.

Comment: YOu can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in to detect the database file version

Comment: Check if you have the newest version of the sqlCompact framework in your project. You might have a database thats NEWER than your sqlCe driver.

Answer (score 0):

The Insert Query is wrong.

the correct format is:

"Insert INTO TableName (Fields delimitted with comma) Values(DiffvaluesDelimited with comma)"